# Can I set a wifi router connect to switch?

Tags: router, switch

ROOM A has a internet router. A cable is connected from internet router to switch. There are four computer connected to the switch in Room A. Each computer has unique ip address.

ROOM B has another switch connected to switch in ROOM A. The switch is connected to four computers too. Each computer has unique ip address too.

The question now. Can I set a wifi router connect to switch in ROOM B? Will it make the ip address conflict? Should I disable DCHP in wifi router?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't purchased your Wifi Router, get an Wifi Access Point instead, and connect it to the switch in Room B.

But if you *already* have that Wifi Router, you simply need to configure your it to operate in **Access Point** mode (instead of the default Wireless Router mode).  In this way all computers in Room B asks for an IP address from the DHCP server in Room A's router.  All computers in Room A and Room B will then be in the same LAN, sharing the same subnet mask, same gateway, and dipping from the same IP address pool.

If your Wifi Router doesn't explicitly offer that option, **turn off DHCP in the Wifi Router** and potentially perform other steps such as those described in [this article](https://www.cnet.com/home/internet/how-to-turn-an-old-wi-fi-router-into-an-access-point/).

Answer (score 1):

What you should be looking for is either a "powerline ethernet adaptor" or "wireless access point".

A router is overkill and will result in the conflicts you mention. If you must use a router, check if it has a "transparent" or "bridge" mode that effectively disables it as a router and turns it into a dumb switch.

It is not just that IP address conflicts are a problem, it is that the router essentially splits the network and without proper configuration of *both* routers you can cause odd issues where the network in Room B can get to the internet, but machines in Room A cannot connect to machines in Room B and vice versa.

Unless you actually *want* that type of split network you are better off getting wireless mesh devices, wireless access points, wireless range extenders, powerline ethernet converters, or any number of devices designed to extend an existing network rather than create a new one.